# (sda) Assuming drive cache: write through hang on boot

Tags: linux, grub2, esxi, centos-7

I just install CentOS 7 on VMware EXSi 6.0 with encryption.
and after the configuration and boot i got it hang with message:

```
[sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

I did search on Internet and found that I need to remove rhgb quite.
but the problem here is, I can't find a guideline on how to remove it.

During boot, I press <kbd>E</kbd> and then, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
then it come to prompt:

```
grub>_
```

But then, what command I need to enter in to remove rhgb quite?

I'm new to CentOS.